# Sending Commands to a Remote Printer

Tags: printing, cross-browser, cross-platform

I'm working on a web project in which I need to be able to communicate directly with my customer's printer. The customer uses my application through a browser, and would like to be able to click a button to print tickets uninterrupted, meaning there is no printer dialog popup from the browser. This requirement eliminates many traditional ways of sending information to the customer's printer, and because I want a solution that will work on any browser, solutions that use VBSCRIPT or other browser-dependent solutions will not work.

My initial solution for this problem was to create a Java applet that was loaded into the page dynamically when a "Print" button was clicked. However, browsers like Chrome and soon Firefox are removing support for NPAPI, which breaks my Java plugin.

The current solution I'm working on is to create a service in C# that the user installs locally on their machine, and then when the customer clicks the "Print" button, my server communicates with that service directly. This way I can bypass the browser restrictions, and the service running on the customer's machine will have full access to communicate with the target printer. The downside to this approach is that the user now has to install an additional bit of software on their machine, and for each machine they wish to access my application on and print from, that machine needs to have proper port-forwarding and firewall settings configured. I can make this work for my current customer, but with future customers it becomes a hassle. Furthermore, my new approach currently only supports Windows machines, and if future customers are using OS X or Linux, I will need to port the service.

Has anyone faced this problem before, or are there any ideas out there for how to communicate with a client's printer that is browser-independent?

Answer (score 0):

There's no possible solution to this that both supports Chrome and doesn't require something to be installed on the machine; you can't run arbitrary code that interfaces with the OS from within Chrome. And the only way to interact with that other code besides a local web server would be Native Messaging in an extension, but that doesn't fulfill your cross-browser requirement.

Answer (score 0):

you can't communication directly because of security. i also develop 1 application in c# for remotely printing.
there is one way if your client have remote printer then you can do this task easily make small app on server and integrate with all remote printer and you can execute printer command from server and print will comes from client printer